# Can InnoSetup create a setup.zip?

Tags: inno-setup

I have Innosetup create a setup.exe. However, if I attach this to an email, people's email anti-malware servers will strip out the exe file attachments.

I can get around this issue by creating a .zip file that contains the exe. I then attach the zip file to email.

Can I get InnoSetup to automate this?

- by setting options in the InnoSetup script?
- some other way involving external programs and post-processing?

Comment: The usual (and safest) way to avoid this problem is not to email the file at all, but to email instead a download link for them to get the file. This avoids the whole "attachment as malware" issue, as well as not asking users to violate the "don't run attachments" training they all receive.

Comment: Most email providers (GMail is one) sniff ZIP files and strip them out if they contain EXE's or BAT files.  I agree with Ken White - I use box.com for delivering release installables.  Box gives you 10Gb for free and you can drag and drop your files into the browser window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no script option for self-zipping of the output binary as far as I know. But you can make a batch script and run the compilation from command line. Or use a tool like e.g. [`ISTool`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/istool/) or [`InnoIDE`](http://www.innoide.net/screenshots.html), whose allow you to define and run post compilation steps in which you can zip the output binary.